# C# - How many times a specific int value appears in array? No Linq tech

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

Have seen many answers on SO, but could not find an appropriate.

I need an efficient algorithm or perhaps method in C# to count *how many times a specific int value appears in array*. **Without Linq**. The size of array is >= 100 and each element is not greater than 100

Having this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)   // get each number for counting
    {
       counter = 0;                 // zero counter for next number comparison

       for (int a = 0; a < array.Length; i++) 
       {
            if (i == array[a])
            {
                counter++;
                if (max < counter) max = counter;   // save max-appeared num
            }   
       }
    }
```

It displays me as result message "Terminated due to timeout" in test challenge. I suppose this code needs much time to be solved. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: The code seems to be at odds with your description. Do you need to 1) count how many occurrences there is of *one specific value* (then why the `max` variable and the outer loop)? 2) count how many occurrences there is of every unique value (if not, why the outer loop)? 3) find which value that has the most occurrences in the array (the max variable)? 4) which how many times (but not which number) the number with the most occurrences occurs?

Comment: You're right..I should be more specific. Yeah, I am talking about 3 :)

Comment: If the numbers in the array is not greater than 100 (and I assume 0 or higher as well), then simply create an array with 101 slots (if 0 is included), then for each number in the array increase the corresponding slot in that array. After you've gone through the array *once*, you can go through this 101-element array and find out which element occurs the most. Most likely the timeout is because of 10x(very big array)

Comment: Nice tip. I will try. Tnx

Comment: When you say _no linq_ do you mean also no _generics_? because the two thing are not the same

Comment: Without generics too. Suppose it is a simple problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit

> each element is *not greater than 100*

and declare all frequencies as an *array* (which has to be of `101` items only: `[0..100]`):

```
int[] freqs = new int[101];

foreach (var item in array)
  freqs[item] += 1;
```

output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < freqs.Length; ++i)
  Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} times", i, freqs[i]);
```

In general case, with *arbitrary large* items you have to deal with *dictionary*:

```
Dictionary<int, int> freqs = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (var item in array) {
  int v;

  if (freqs.TryGetValue(item, out v)) 
    freqs[item] = v + 1;
  else 
    freqs.Add(1);
}
```

output (not sorted):

```
foreach (var pair in freqs)
  Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} times", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Program Code:

```
int[] num = { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0 };
int[] count = new int[10];

//Loop through 0-9 and count the occurances
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < num.Length; y++)
        if (num[y] == x)
            count[x]++;

//For displaying output only            
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    Console.WriteLine("Number " + x + " appears " + count[x] + " times");
```

Program Output:

```
Number 0 appears 1 times
Number 1 appears 3 times
Number 2 appears 0 times
Number 3 appears 2 times
Number 4 appears 1 times
Number 5 appears 1 times
Number 6 appears 1 times
Number 7 appears 1 times
Number 8 appears 0 times
```

I understand how bad it feels when all your classmates had finish theirs, and you are still struggling. My codes should be simple enough for your learning.

Comment: How would this code improve on the timeout problem? Since his numbers are up to 100, the outer loop will be up to 100 (like his), and the array is provided by a test system (I assume online code ranking or similar), which is likely to be **big**, hence the timeout. Since you've gone through the trouble of creating an array for the counters you can dispense with the outer loop completely, assuming you know the boundaries of the values and they are reasonable.

Comment: I don't see main difference with mine solution. We have 100 elements and not 10 as mentioned v. Karsen. No need to display output appears. Can't understand why vote to answer if it's the same?!

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid to execute two loops

```
// Prepare the test array (this is done before entering the counting loop)
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] array = new int[100]; // 100 or whatever....
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] = rnd.Next(1, 101);  // 1-100 range

// The max occurences of a number
int maxOccurence = 0;
// The number with the max occurences
int currentMax = 0;

// One bigger to accomodate the 100....
int[] occurrences = new int[array.Length + 1];

// Loop and check on the test array
for (int a = 0; a < array.Length; a++)
{
    // The current number to examine
    int number = array[a];

    // Increment the occurences counter for the number
    occurrences[number]++;

    // Check if we have a new max....
    if (occurrences[number] > maxOccurence)
    {
        // Save the new leader, both the new max occurence and number 
        maxOccurence = occurrences[number];
        currentMax = number;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(maxOccurence);
Console.WriteLine(currentMax);
```

However this still cannot detect if two or more number have the same occurence count.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var counters = new int[101]; // 0 to 100
var max = 0;
var maxCount = 0;

foreach (var n in input)
{
    counters[n] = counters[n] + 1;
    if (counters[n] > maxCount)
    {
        maxCount = counters[n];
        max = n;
    }
}

return max;
```